I volunteer at an animal shelter: What can I do to protect my pet rabbit from exposure to RHDV?
I have a three-year-old rabbit who is in good health. She receives an annual booster for RHDV2, which can be deadly for rabbits.
Recently, I started volunteering at a local animal shelter. I'm in contact with unvaccinated rabbits as well as other animals. I make sure that I take my shoes off before I come home, wash my hands thoroughly before leaving the shelter and again when I arrive home, and change my clothes right away.
I really enjoy volunteering, but I want to make sure I'm not potentially putting my pet at risk due to my exposure to unvaccinated rabbits and other animals. Is there anything else I can do to help protect my pet at home?

It sounds like you're doing everything that's recommended to keep your rabbit safe. That with the vaccination is really the best. But I understand and appreciate your concern! Here are some other options:

Take a full shower after volunteering, not just your hands.
Keep a set of "volunteer-only" clothes and shoes, and keep them in your garage/car/ somewhere the rabbit will never be. Change before you go, and then take them off in the garage when you're home (this is what my nursing friends do when they are exposed to viruses at work). Use a garbage bag to transfer your clothes to the wash when needed.
Use a disinfectant (bleach or other solutions) on things you can't wash (shoes, door handles, car keys).
Consider only helping with other animals. I'm sure your got into volunteering because you love rabbits, but maybe, you should only work with the cats, dogs, etc. This is only for peace of mind, though, as you are already well informed and taking great precautions.

